# Minimum eigenvalue of the difference of two Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$.

Weyl's inequality tells us that $$\lambda_{\min}(A + B) \ge \lambda_{\min}(A) + \lambda_{\min}(B) $$
See this link for proof: [Smallest eigenvalues of Sum of Two Positive Matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210024/smallest-eigenvalues-of-sum-of-two-positive-matrices)

How can we bound $\lambda_{\min}(A - B)$, given the the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lambda_{min}(A) - \lambda_{max}(B)$?!

Comment: That's what I thought. But just wanted to get to verify it.

Comment: @ssk08 it suffices to note that $\lambda_{min}(-B) = -\lambda_{max}(B)$